# How to display image when click on it picasso

Tags: java, android

Currently I am using Picasso library to load images from URL in my Gridview. I want when the user clicks on the image display the image, how can I do that? , I searched for a long time for a solution to this problem but I have not found things.

that is my codes

**PicassoImagesAdapter.java**

```
public class PicassoImagesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

private String[] imageUrls;
private ImageView ImageBanner;

public PicassoImagesAdapter(Context context, String[] imageUrls) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_images, imageUrls);

    this.context = context;
    this.imageUrls = imageUrls;

    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (null == convertView) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_images, parent, false);
    }

    Picasso
            .with(context)
            .load(imageUrls[position])
            .fit() // to resize the image to imageView
            .transform(new PicassoRoundedTransformation(20, 0)) // Add radius to the images
            .noFade()
            .into((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_image));

    return convertView;
}
}
```

**ImagesRamadanActivity.java**

```
public class ImagesRamadanActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ramadan_images);

    // ArrayList for RamadanImages
    String[] RamadanImages = {
            "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_1280.jpg",
            "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_1280.jpg",
            "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_1280.jpg",
            "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_1280.jpg",
            "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_1280.jpg",
            "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_1280.jpg",
            "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_1280.jpg",
            "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_1280.jpg",
            "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_1280.jpg",
    };
    // Find that view to display all the photos in Array on it
    GridView gridView2 = findViewById(R.id.gridview_image_ramadan);
    gridView2.setAdapter(new PicassoImagesAdapter(ImagesRamadanActivity.this, RamadanImages));
```

**activity_ramadan_images.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fff"
tools:context=".ImagesRamadanActivity">

<!--Toolbar-->
<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_ramadan_images"
    layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

<!-- Loading indicator for user feedback between queries to Guardian -->
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/loading_indicator5"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview_image_ramadan"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_ramadan_images"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
    android:scrollbars="none" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

This activity to display images as a list to display them in gridView 
**list_images.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/list_image"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    tools:src="@drawable/button_kabba_image"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity to display the photo when clicking on it **activity_image_display.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/display_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `ItemClickListener` on your `GridView` and then get the `imageURL` that the user has clicked on. Then you need to launch `DisplayImageActivity` with it.

you can try the following code inside `ImagesRamadanActivity`:

```
 gridView2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // get the image
            String image = RamadanImages[position];
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,ImageActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("imageUrl",image);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Once you have the data inside `DisplayImageActivity` you can display it in your `ImageView` with `Picasso.`

Your activity code could be similar to the following code:

```
 public class DisplayImageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_display);

            ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.display_image);
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            if (intent.hasExtra("imageUrl")){
                String url = intent.getStringExtra("imageUrl");
                Picasso.with(this)
                        .load(url)
                        .into(imageView);
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: Excuse me because I am still new in Android
Now I created a new class called DisplayImageActivity
What do I do next?

Comment: Also, it gives me this error when I add the class in intent " the error: lambda expressions are not supported at The language level 7

Comment: I have added DisplayImageActivity code. Also, I have updated the answer to avoid using lambda expressions. But it's recommended to update your project to Java 8

Comment: Thank you very very much :D, relly you saved my day